# Import python from different folder without using .py extension

Tags: python, python-import, python-2.x

Import python from different folder without using .py extension

Below is my python script (feed_prg) that calls the python script (distribute)

Please note that my script are at different location

`feed_prg` is at location /opt/callscript

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
sys.path.append('/home/username')
import distribute


# Main method start execution
def main(argv):
     something = 'some'
     distribute.feed(something)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv[1:])
```

`distribute` is at location `/home/username`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def feed(something):
       print something

def main():
        something= "some"
        feed(something)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I am seeing the below error while executing ./feed_prg , and only when my distribute filename is just distribute and not distribute.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./feed_prg", line XX, in <module>
    import distribute
ImportError: No module named distribute
```

the distribute also has the execute privilege, as below

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username 3028 Dec 16 21:05 distribute`

How can I fix this. ? Any inputs will be helpful

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using `import` directly. It's best to simply rename the file to `.py`

That being said, it's possible to load the module into a variable using `importlib` or `imp` depending on your Python version.

---

Given the following file at path `./distribute` (relative to where python is run):

```
# distribute

print("Imported!")
a_var = 5
```

**Python 2**

```py
# python2import

from imp import load_source

distribute = load_source("distribute", "./distribute")
print(distribute.a_var)
```

Usage:

```
$ python python2import
Imported!
5
```

**Python 3**

```py
#python3import

from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

distribute = SourceFileLoader("distribute", "./distribute").load_module()
print(distribute.a_var)
```

Usage:

```
$ python3 python3import
Imported!
5
```

Comment: Let me try that, though we are on older version of Python (Python 2.6.6)